# Cannot invoke replace(String, String) on the array type String[]

Tags: java, string, jsp

While trying to work with manipulation of strings on jsp, I used string.repalace(), method in my code but I am getting following errors persistently:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /final2.jsp
Cannot invoke replace(String, String) on the array type String[]
6:       public void main (String str) {
7:      String [] text = StringUtils.substringsBetween(str,"#","#");
8:      for (int i=0; i<text.length;i++) {
9:        String newtext = text.replace("#"+text[i]+"#","<b>"+text[i]+"</b>");
10:          }
11: //blank line
12:     }


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:     102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

My code is as follows:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*"      errorPage="" %>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils" %>

<%
 final class setext {
  public void main (String str) {
    String [] text = StringUtils.substringsBetween(str,"#","#");
    for (int i=0; i<text.length;i++) {
      String newtext = text.replace("#"+text[i]+"#","<b>"+text[i]+"</b>");
     }

}

}
%>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
text.replace("#"+text[i]+"#","<b>"+text[i]+"</b>");
```

text is array, you can't call `replace()` on arrays

You need to first get String from array which gives String and call replace on that String.

```
String temp = text[i];
temp.replace("#"+text[i]+"#","<b>"+text[i]+"</b>");
```

Answer (score 1):

`text` is an array of string - you possibly meant:

```
String newtext = text[i].replace("#"+text[i]+"#","<b>"+text[i]+"</b>");
```

where `text[i]` is one of the strings within the text array.

Although looking at it, that statement does make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

If it just to replace "#" as needed :

```
 public void main (String str) {
    String [] text = StringUtils.substringsBetween(str,"#","#");
    for (int i = 0, n = text.length ; i<n; i++) {
        text[i] = text[i].replace("#"+text[i]+"#", "<b>"+text[i]+"</b>");
 }
```

*EDITED*

- add *n* in for(..)
- if your snippet is stressed you can also use a Pattern/Matcher model to replace '#'.